# hostvars for localhost (Ansible master) only grabbing a few facts

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have this line in my playbook:

```
- debug: msg="{{ hostvars['127.0.0.1'] }}"
```

and for some reason it only grabs a handful of facts, primarily around setup of the master.

```
- hosts: mfg-pc:master
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ hostvars['127.0.0.1'] }}"
```

An example of the facts gathered:

```
{
    "msg": {
        "ansible_check_mode": false,
        "ansible_connection": "local",
        "ansible_python_interpreter": "/usr/bin/python",
        "ansible_version": {
            "full": "2.2.0.0",
            "major": 2,
            "minor": 2,
            "revision": 0,
            "string": "2.2.0.0"
        },
        "group_names": [
            "ungrouped"
        ],
        "groups": {
            "all": [
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't grab the full list of variables that I get with:

```
ansible -m setup 127.0.0.1
```

I need the full list of facts as I'm trying to utilize the host (Ansible master) time to time-stamp a file I generate. This behavior seems inconsistent with another machine I was running it on, and I can't for the life of me determine why. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your inventory: you say `hosts: mfg-pc:master`, but in the output there is `"group_names": ["ungrouped"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't gather facts from `localhost` in your playbook so you shouldn't expect Ansible to have them.

You must add a play which will execute `setup` (implicitly) against your `localhost`, for example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

- hosts: mfg-pc:master
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ hostvars['127.0.0.1'] }}"
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this won't work if I use the limit flag and limit it to a host group that doesn't include localhost, correct? I believe this is the reason for my confusion, this was working with an earlier version of ansible (circa 1.9) while in the latest version localhost is not always included.
I'll just find a way to only conditionally run the portions I want on the target devices and skip the master/localhost. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check parameter *gather_subset* into your configuration file *ansible.cfg*. To returns all facts it must be set to *all*:

```
gather_subset = all
```

If needed, to localize your configuration file *ansible.cfg*, type:

```
ansible --version
```

It must returns a line like this :

```
config file = /home/.../ansible.cfg
```